# Nibiru, or Planet X

Tags: hypothetical

What is the popular opinion on this "Planet X" news that I have been seeing? It makes me a little nervous sometimes... I read so much on the internet about this subject and do not know what to believe... Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, this site is not about opinions, and not about space. You can try [Astronomy.SE] but then you'll need to write a better question. What exactly don't you understand? And that site already has a [lot of questions about Planet X](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=planet+x)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, believe nothing that you see on the internet.  Belief is overrated anyway, understanding is better, but if you're going to believe or worry about what you read, then read only verified scientific sources and don't believe anything that shows up on YouTube or other discussions and message boards.  There's tons of bad information out there.

Comment: And, as the answer below suggests, the recently theorized, but not yet discovered planet 9, if it is out there, it's quite harmless.   It doesn't have an orbit that enters the inner solar system and even if it did, it wouldn't enter it for thousands of years.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am very new to this site, so I'm not real sure how to do things. I am very glad to hear what you are saying. It does me a lot of good. I don't watch much TV and don't know the right sites to go to for truthful news. I'm kinda ignorant but really want to learn. Thanks again...

Comment: 'Happy Jane' is quite right to be suspicious. Much of the internet is baloney, and unfortunately, the spam artists have learned how to dress up junk science to closely resemble real science. As 'User LTK' correctly points out, if you want the closest approximation to the truth, stick to peer-reviewed scientific papers, such as those that generally appear in 'Google scholar'  https://scholar.google.com.au/   Some other academic search engines are listed in http://www.educatorstechnology.com/2013/02/12-fabulous-academic-search-engines.html

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to be worried about. There's no magical Niburu or Planet X, if anything then Planet 9 might exist. 
There was a recent [research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05438) that looked at the orbital elements of some trans-Neptunian objects and their curious clustering. The paper suggested that a possbile explanation for this clustering might be shepherding by a possible ninth planet in the solar system.

Then the media made up big stories about magical objects in the sky that have nothing to do with Planet 9. Also I believe this question rather belongs into the astronomy section.

Comment: I very much appreciate your answering my question. I know it's silly to get worried, but sometimes things seem so real. I am quite ignorant about a lot of things. but I want to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: The whole conspiracy theorised Nibiru/PlanetX thing has been around for years; slowly having built on layers and layers of conjecture (as these things do).